# Set additional rule to existing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/e8B9j/2/

HTML

```
<div class="box" style="width:700px">This is a sentence</div>
<div class="box" style="width:600px">This is a sentence</div>
<div class="box" style="width:500px">This is a sentence</div>
<div class="box" style="width:400px">This is a sentence</div>
```

Javascript

```
$( '.box' ).each(function ( i, box ) {

var width = $( box ).width(),
    html = '<span style="white-space:nowrap">',
    line = $( box ).wrapInner( html ).children()[ 0 ],
    n = 100;

$( box ).css( 'font-size', n );

while ( $( line ).width() > width ) {
    $( box ).css( 'font-size', --n );
}

$( box ).text( $( line ).text() );

});
```

How do I make it to check if the font size it is about to set >20px, then make it 20px?

Comment: By the way, the json tag is inappropriate here. A jquery tag would be more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simple ways I can think of right now:

```
Math.max(n, 20) // will output the maximum of n or 20
```

or

```
(n<20 ? 20 : n) // will output 20 if n<20, and n otherwise
```

this means that in your code:

```
// replace
$( box ).css( 'font-size', n );
// with
$( box ).css( 'font-size', Math.max(n, 20) );
```

and

```
// replace
$( box ).css( 'font-size', --n );
// with
$( box ).css( 'font-size', Math.max(--n, 20) );
```

Comment: I'm really sucks in javascript so please provide me the exact code in answer, at least the javascript part

Comment: I added details for the implementation. Would you validate my answer ?